# Licence manager page ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web, licensing

We have an fairly complex enterprise ASP.NET web forms 2.0 app.

We need to deploy this application to our clients who are in closed VPN environment.

Application will be deployed to the instances of our clients(basically one instance is equal to 200 or more client PC's).

We need to create licence manager page where we can configure duration of one licence for all clients within one instance. If the licence expires there will be popup warning for clients that they cannot use the app anymore.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you intend to configure license? Is it per specific client PC based or per user based who can login from any client PC?

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me. We deploy our application totally unprotected in large zip folder which is later on deployed on their server. Let's say that one instance is 200 or more client PC's. I do not care whether it is one universal key with strict (from to date of duration) or if the each individual key is generated on client pc as long as I am able to universally control from LicenceManager.aspx page the duration of licence. When the date has passed I want to deny the access to the page to all clients in one instance. I really hope that you have understood me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have only one license per server, no matter how many clients and users are there. If the application license on server expires it will be not be accessible from any client by any user (except the admin console / license manager).

In such a case you can have a database entity (or XML or any other file as suites your requirements) that stores license information in encrypted form such as License Start Date, Expiry Date, No of Users, License Type, Issued By, Issued To etc.

Depending upon your application type and requirement, these credentials can be checked:

1. Upon every request (might affect performance) or
2. Upon every login by the clients (this seems to be a better approach) or

On license verification, if the license has expired then you may redirect the user to the license page.

Your license manager should be accessible only via a separate login

This scenario can be implemented only if do not deploy your code on the server i.e. you provide only compiled assembly to the client.

**Update**

Multiple validations can be applied for license tampering such as:

1. If the license code field is empty, user must be redirected to the registration page.
2. If the encrypted license code has been modified then redirect to registration page.

Comment: Thanks. I have came up with solution of using Rhino library. The problem is that I do not now where to hide private key because our clients have the access to our own db, as the matter of fact they set it up for us.